# If inflation is an exponential expansion, is the exponent known?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, cosmological-inflation

Inflation is often called exponential expansion.

I can't seem to find what that exponent is. Is it 2, or 20, or completely unknown?

Comment: It is bounded experimentally but quite uncertain and model dependent. There are charts showing the bounds of the relevant parameters from observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cosmic inflation, the Friedmann scale factor $a(t)$ of the universe doesn’t grow as some power of the time, such as $a\sim t^2$ or $a\sim t^{20}$. These are *not* exponential expansions at all. Exponential expansion means that time appears *in the exponent*: $a\sim e^{t/\tau}$ or $a\sim 2^{t/\tau}$ or $a\sim 10^{t/\tau}$ or whatever you prefer to use as the base to be exponentiated. Physicists normally use $e$, the base of the natural logarithms, so let’s go with $e^{t/\tau}$. Using a different base just changes $\tau$ a bit.

In inflation, the characteristic time $\tau$ for the scale factor to increase by a factor of $e$ (which is about 2.7) is *fantastically small*: typically around a trillionth of a trillionth of a trillionth of a second! That’s $10^{-36}$ seconds. In various inflation models it might be bigger or smaller by a few orders of magnitude, but it is always fantastically small.

So in just $10^{-36}$ seconds everything in the universe got 2.7 times further apart. In another $10^{-36}$ seconds it grew by another factor of 2.7. In another $10^{-36}$ seconds it grew by another factor of 2.7. After 60 $e$-foldings the scale factor is 100,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 times larger, and this took just, say, 60 trillionths of a trillionth of a trillionth of a second.

It is truly one of the most astounding ideas in the history of physics.

Comment: For comparison, the universe is still undergoing exponential expansion, but $\tau$ at present is the Hubble time, on the order of $10^{17}\ \mathrm{s}$ (455 Ps) - 53 _orders of magnitude_ longer, and thus, slower.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer I would say that it is *again* undergoing exponential expansion, because there were times when the expansion was non-exponential, during the radiation-dominated and matter-dominated eras.

Comment: To put the scale in the quantum context, the inflation characteristic time $\tau$ is $10^{-36}/10^{-44} = 10^8$ Planck time. Therefore, quantum effects are not of major concern in inflationary models. The inflation uniformly spreads out the quantum fluctuations seeded prior to the inflationary epoch.